# typescript functions with `this` parameter

Tags: typescript, function, class, interface, this

Is there a way in typescript to add functionalities to an existing class/interface?

Let me give you an example: In C# it's possible to do something on the line of:

```cs
function addSayingHi(this Array, var element){
   console.log("hi, I am " + element);
   this.add(element);
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is something like this:

```js
export interface ILeaderBoard {
  title: string;
  leaderboard: ILeaderBoardPosition[];
}

export function rankIt(this: ILeaderBoard) {
  /* TODO */
}
```

For this specific case I will probably just make a class out of it, but it would be nice to know  for future uses (e.g: if i wish to extend console's functionalities with a library)

Comment: You cannot do exactly what you asked: it's impossible to extend an interface with implementation. Interfaces don't exist in runtime, hence you cannot extend it. But you can monkey-patch an implementation of that interface (eg. a class, via its prototype). From this perspective your C# example is irrelevant, because you extend a an `Array` class with an extension method, not an interface.

Comment: I wish this example were more complete; like a `class` instead of an `interface` with some toy implementation of what you'd like to add to it, we can show you how to do it with adding to the class's `prototype` (so it works at runtime) as well as using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) (so it works at design time).   Without a more concrete example I'd just point you to the documentation for [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

Comment: Is [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sjgpag?file=index.ts) what you're looking for?  Let me know and I'll write it up.  Otherwise, please elaborate on your use case.  Good luck!

Comment: @zerkms I imagined it, but not being 100% sure it was worth asking

Comment: @jcalz it would be the solution I was looking for, would you add it as an answer, so I can accept it?